# Pandas find common NA records across multiple large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have 3 dataframes like as shown below

```
ID,col1,col2
1,X,35
2,X,37
3,nan,32
4,nan,34
5,X,21
df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',',skipinitialspace=True)

ID,col1,col2
1,nan,305
2,X,307
3,X,302
4,nan,304
5,X,201
df2 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',',skipinitialspace=True)

ID,col1,col2
1,X,315
2,nan,317
3,X,312
4,nan,314
5,X,21
df3 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',',skipinitialspace=True)
```

Now I want to identify the `IDs` where `col1` is `NA` in all 3 input dataframes.

So, I tried the below

```
L1=df1[df1['col1'].isna()]['ID'].tolist()
L2=df2[df2['col1'].isna()]['ID'].tolist()
L3=df3[df3['col1'].isna()]['ID'].tolist()
common_ids_all = list(set.intersection(*map(set, [L1,L2,L3])))
final_df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],ignore_index=True)
final_df[final_df['ID'].isin(common_ids_all)]
```

While the above works, is there any efficient and elegant approach do the above?

As you can see that am repeating the same statement thrice (for 3 dataframes)

However, in my real data, I have 12 dataframes where I have to get IDs where `col1` is NA in all 12 dataframes.

**update - my current read operation looks like below**

```
fnames = ['file1.xlsx','file2.xlsx', 'file3.xlsx']
dfs=[]
NA_list=[]
def preprocessing(fname):
    df= pd.read_excel(fname, sheet_name="Sheet1")
    df.columns = df.iloc[7]
    df = df.iloc[8: , :]
    NA_list.append(df[df['col1'].isna()]['ID'])
    dfs.append(df)
[preprocessing(fname) for fname in fnames]
final_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
L1 = NA_list[0]
L2 = NA_list[1]
L3 = NA_list[2]
final_list = (list(set.intersection(*map(set, [L1,L2,L3]))))
final_df[final_df['ID'].isin(final_list)]
```

Comment: Use `skiprows=6` to read your files: `df= pd.read_excel(fname, sheet_name="Sheet1", skiprows=6)` and remove the next two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
final_df = pd.concat(dfs).query('col1.isna()')
final_df = final_df[final_df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size') == len(dfs)]
print(final_df)

# Output
   ID col1  col2
3   4  NaN    34
3   4  NaN   304
3   4  NaN   314
```

Full code:

```
fnames = ['file1.xlsx','file2.xlsx', 'file3.xlsx']

def preprocessing(fname):
    return pd.read_excel(fname, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=6)

dfs = [preprocessing(fname) for fname in fnames]
final_df = pd.concat([df[df['col1'].isna()] for df in dfs])
final_df = final_df[final_df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size') == len(dfs)]
```

Comment: the query function - queries the concatenated full dataframe or it concatenates only rows where col1 is NA?

Comment: Here the whole dataframes but it's easy to get only the subset with NaN. Do you want this version instead?

Comment: I get error in query function though. `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isna'`

Comment: Try with `final_df = pd.concat([df[df['col1'].isna()] for df in dfs])`

Comment: I wrote `col1`.isna(). Even if I write `col1.isna()` - I get another error - `IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 8`

Answer (score 1):

This are times when def function get you sorted. If the dataframe list will continually change I will create a def function. If I got you right the following will do;

```
def CombinedNaNs(lst):
newdflist =[]
for d in dflist:
    newdflist.append(d[d['col1'].isna()])
    s=pd.concat(newdflist)
    
return s[s.duplicated(subset=['ID'], keep=False)].drop_duplicates()

 dflist=[df1,df2,df3]#List of dfs

CombinedNaNs(dflist)#apply function



    ID col1  col2
3   4  NaN    34
3   4  NaN   304
3   4  NaN   314
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted for the help. I have given my existing code where I read multiple file using def function. Do you think your piece of code can be accomodated into my finction? can help me?

Comment: your output is incorrect I guess. We should get only ID = 4

Comment: Yes, that would be the right thing to do

Comment: because ID=4 is NA in all 3 dataframes whereas other ID's like 1 or 2 don't have NA in all 3 dataframmes